# Puma caught this error: undefined method `helper_method' for ActionController::API:Class (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

**Puma caught this error: undefined method `helper_method' for ActionController::API:Class (NoMethodError)**

Error Line: `.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/google-webfonts-rails-0.0.1/lib/google-webfonts/rails/helpers.rb:7:in block in <module:Helpers>`

Gemfile:

```
ruby '2.4.0'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.3'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
```

**ApplicationController**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  #include ActionController::Helpers
  include Devise::Controllers::Helpers
end
```

Comment: Whatever controller is being called here does not inherit from ApplicationController as it inherits from ActionController::API and not Base. You need to actually look at the stack trace and show us the actual code that raises the error.

Comment: This was tricky for me to track down. I ended up putting a `binding.pry` right before `Application.initialize!` and then called `Application.initialize!` from the debugging console. The stack trace here was more valuable and lead me to an outdated version of the `breadcrumbs_on_rails` gem. I needed to update it from 2.3.1 to 4.0.0. Hopefully that helps somebody else.